# jQuery method .after() [like .html()] inserting plain text instead of HTML on iPhone

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone

[image: iPhone screenshot]

The code:

```js
let screen_width = $( window ).width()
$('a.button[href^="tel:"]').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  show_phone_numbers();
  if (screen_width < 768) window.location.href = jQuery(this).attr('href');
  //   localStorage.setItem("show_phone_numbers", Date.now());
});
//phone_numbers_opened = localStorage.getItem("show_phone_numbers");
if (typeof phone_numbers_opened !== 'undefined' && phone_numbers_opened != null) {
  if (phone_numbers_opened == '1') {
    //    localStorage.removeItem("show_phone_numbers");
  } else {
    phone_numbers_opened = parseInt(phone_numbers_opened);
    if (Date.now() - phone_numbers_opened < 86400000)
      show_phone_numbers();
  }
}

function show_phone_numbers() {
  $('a.button[href^="tel:"]').each(function() {
    $parent = jQuery(this).hide().parent();
    $noscript = $parent.find('noscript.show-phone');
    jQuery(this).after($noscript.html());
    $noscript.remove();
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<noscript class="show-phone"><a href="tel:+1 (234) 567-89-00" class="topmenu__phone">+1 (234) 567-89-00</a></noscript>
<a href="tel:+1 (234) 567-89-00" class="topmenu__phone button button--small"><svg><use href="#icon_call"/></svg> Call us</a>
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Only on iPhone?

Comment: @mplungjan Yes, only on iPhone. Previous answer I don't understood. The site is on screenshot

Comment: It was not an answer. It was a request to show the relevant code. How can we help just by looking at a picture of a screen?

Comment: @mplungjan pasted HTML and JS here: https://pastebin.com/aEVfFN8N

Comment: I made you a working snippet from your code. Please revert if that is not ok.

Comment: I can reproduce using this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/Lnujf7kb/

Comment: @mplungjan Fiddle is right, I only not see changes in phone show code. Also I tried solution from other thread with creating ghost element and getting text() from it `$noscript.after(jQuery("<div/>").html($noscript.html()).text());`, but it also don't work and pasting plain text intead of HTML

Comment: @mplungjan I tried some another way and it's worked! `$noscript.after(jQuery('<textarea/>').html($noscript.text()).text());`. Thank you for helping